# Concatenate strings in file_line resource

Tags: regex, puppet, interpolation, string-interpolation

I'm trying to concatenate a string in a puppet manifest like so:

```
file_line {'Append to /etc/hosts':
  ensure => present,
  line =>  "${networking['ip'] + '\t'}${networking['fqdn'] + '\t'}${networking['hostname']}",
  match => "${'^#?'+ networking['ip'] + '\s+' + networking['fqdn'] + '\s+' + networking['hostname']}",
  path =>  '/etc/hosts'
}
```

I either get syntax errors or in the case above:

> The value '' cannot be converted to Numeric

Which I'm guessing means that it doesn't like the plus operator.
So how do I interpolate the strings in the `match` and `line` attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the operator `+` is restricted to only `Numeric` types ([documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_expressions.html#addition)). It cannot be used with `String` types. However, the spacing and regular expressions can still be used as normal without attempting a string concatenate. These merely need to be placed outside the variable interpolation. Therefore:

```
file_line { 'Append to /etc/hosts':
  ensure => present,
  line   => "${networking['ip']}\t${networking['fqdn']}\t${networking['hostname']}",
  match  => "^#?${networking['ip']}\s+${networking['fqdn']}\s+${networking['hostname']}",
  path   => '/etc/hosts'
}
```

should resolve your issues with the type mismatch and the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

i know you already got your answer, but you can make life easier using `host` to manage `/etc/hosts`:

```
host {
    "localhost": ip => "127.0.0.1";

    "$::puppet_server":
        ip           => "1.2.3.4",
        host_aliases => [ "puppetserver" ],
    ;

    "dns-01.tld":
        ip           => "1.2.3.5",
        host_aliases => [ "dns-01" ],
    ;

    "dns-02.tld":
        ip           => "1.2.3.6",
        host_aliases => [ "dns-02" ],
    ;
}
```